# Firefox intermittently sets all colors on a page (text, background, links, highlighted text, etc.) to a single color, on both Android and Windows

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-color, textcolor

This has been happening on Firefox for Android (57.0.1, Android 8.1.0, Security patch level: December 5,2017 -- but I cannot be totally sure that it has happened since the most update, since I have automatic updates on), and just happened on Firefox ESR (52.5.2, 32-bit, updates disabled by sysadmin, on Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1703):

While I am browsing, the page I am on will, from time to time, become a solid mass of uniform color. Using "Inspect Element" and copy-and-pasting both make it clear that the contents of the page are still *there*; they've just become the same color as the background. Whether the color in question is a background color or a text color seems to be consistent for a given page, but not necessarily between pages.

When this happens, it applies to every other page I open in Firefox, including an "HTML" file that consists of the single character "A" (black-on-black, unlike a completely blank "html" file, which is white). The only solution is to close Firefox and reopen it, at which point everything works fine until the next time that this happens.

On the Windows machine, all settings that turn up when searching about:config for "color" are default other than settings for a particular printer that's hooked up to it.

Incidentally, while I was typing this up the first time, I tried to Inspect Element on a "just the letter A" "html" file, since things were working fine, and Firefox started screwing up the background and text colors of *parts* of pages, which had not happened previously. (Hence my initially posting a half-finished version of this question, in order to avoid losing it entirely.)

I want to know why this is happening, and how to prevent it from happening in the future and/or fix it once it has happened, other than by quitting Firefox and losing anything I have in progress.

ETA: This has now happened twice on this Youtube page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSFfhS4pKHg&index=19&list=PL9e3UCcU00TQmv44PITdAgihDTDehgMki and at least once in GMail (don't remember what page, and naturally, it wouldn't display for someone not logged into my account). So there may be a common Google connection; I don't know.